# Two results about a topological direct sum

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, analysis

I have been struggling to prove the following results for some time and really hope someone can help me out.

Let $V$ be a vector space with two subspaces $W$ and $Z$. If $\tau_V$ is a topology that makes $V$ a topological vector space, then we say $V$ is a topological direct sum of $W$ and $Z$, written as $V = W \oplus_{top} Z$ if for any $v \in V$, there exists unique $w \in W, z \in Z$ such that $v = w_v + z_v$ and the projection maps $p_W(v) = w_v, p_Z(v) = z_v$ are continuous. Here on $W$ and $Z$ we use the subset topology.

The two results I want to prove are:

1. If $V = W \oplus_{top} Z$, then $W$ and $Z$ are closed.
2. If $V$ is a Banach space (so $\tau_V$ is induced by a norm), $W$ and $Z$ are closed, and for any $v \in V$, there exists unique $w \in W, z \in Z$ such that $v = w_v + z_v$, then $V = W \oplus_{top} Z$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: In my lecturer notes, I was suggested to construct a homeomorphism between $V$ and $W \times Z$. But I could not prove continuity for both directions, kind of frustrated by the notes as the contents are pretty arcane......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 1, let me prove that $W$ is closed as proving that $Z$ is closed is analogous. First, note that $V\backslash \{0\}$ is open in $V$, and therefore, $Z\backslash \{0\}$ is open in $Z$. Hence, $p_Z^{-1}(Z\backslash \{0\})$ is open in $V$.

It is left to show that $V\backslash W = P_Z^{-1}(Z\backslash \{0\})$. Indeed,

$$v\in W \iff p_W(v)=v \iff p_Z(v)=0$$
(I'll leave a formal proof of this as an exercise). This completes the proof of $1$.

For 2, we need to show that $p_W: V\rightarrow W$ is continuous. Check out this answer
[All projections are continuous in a Banach space.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1432664/all-projections-are-continuous-in-a-banach-space)

Comment: Thanks for you help, I have a question, is $\{0\}$ always closed for a general topological vector space?

Comment: @zlbi [$\{0\}$ is closed iff the TVS is Hausdorff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_vector_space#Non-Hausdorff_spaces_and_the_closure_of_the_origin), however authors like Rudin put that assumption in their definition of TVSs (see the Definition paragraph).

Comment: Hi, does this mean my first result is true only when the TVS is Hausdorff?

Comment: @zlbi yes that's correct. If $\{0\}$ is not closed then in particular $V = V\oplus_{top} \{0\}$ (take $W=\{0\}$ and $Z=V$), then $W$ is not closed.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation!